# Capture the Non-Active UIView as an UIImage

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios4

The code below works well but grabs only the UIView which is VISIBLE on your screen.
How can I grab instead a UIView which is not currently displaying?

Thanks!

```
    //Take a screenshot of the view...
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(View_1.frame.size);
    [View_1.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *View_1 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(View_1, nil, nil, nil);

//...and attach it as an image to the email
NSData *myData3 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(View_1);
[picker addAttachmentData:myData3 mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"screenshot2"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean hidden like in `view.hidden = YES;` then you will not be able to draw it, instead of hiding it you can either remove it from the super view, or even call `view.hidden = NO;` before drawing it and then `view.hidden = YES;` after it has been drawn

example

```
//Take a screenshot of the view...
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(View_1.frame.size);
//Set it to visible
View_1.hidden = NO;
[View_1.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *View_1 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(View_1, nil, nil, nil);
//Hide it again
View_1.hidden = YES;
//...and attach it as an image to the email
NSData *myData3 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(View_1);
[picker addAttachmentData:myData3 mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"screenshot2"];
```

Comment: You are a genius! It was indeeed set to hidden... Many thanks for your help. :-)

Comment: Although not very pertinent to the title of the question...do you know if it is possible to add more than 1 image to the attachment?