# How to capture pictures of the whole scroll view without showing the view to the user

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I am implementing print functionality in my application for which I want to send a picture of the screen to the printer SDK.

I am creating a dummy view on which I have a Scroll View and on this Scrollview I have a list a list of products to print added as a subview. The height of this scroll view is larger than the screen size of the iPad as the list is quite big.

I want to capture pictures of the whole Scroll View with the whole list (the list with products not visible and out or UIScreen). Also, I don't want this view to be visible to the user. Everything should happen in the background.

Comment: Possibly Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539717/getting-a-screenshot-of-a-uiscrollview-including-offscreen-parts.

Answer (score 0):

You can render the view in scrollview and get a `UIImage` of that.

In the code below the view `viewInScrollView` is subview in `UIScrollView` and all elements are present in that view.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(scrollView.contentSize)      
viewInScrollView.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
var myImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

the `myImage` variable will have the image of whole `scrollView`.

Comment: shouldn't you make the size the same size as the contentView as the contents could be larger than the view size

Comment: sorry updating the code, forgot to change that part. Thanks

Comment: How to do this without presenting the view to the user? If I do hide the view the crash on this UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext occurs.

Comment: @akshaytule here is a related issue, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11061850/capture-the-non-active-uiview-as-an-uiimage , I hope it will answer your question. 
In the accepted solution the guy said you can remove from superview instead of hiding.